# Using (parts of) Wordpress Themes in xpages

Tags: wordpress, themes, xpages

Not sure if this is a stupid question or not,
but i want to create a better looking notes database which should remind users of our companys homepage.

Is it possible to use codes extracts of the wordpress themes css code?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to start with the Bootstrap4 XPages plugin on openNTF and then work to skin that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as CSS stylesheets don't reference by element ID, it's possible to utilise elements. However, bear in mind that parts of the CSS stylesheets you're using may get overwritten by inline styles or stylesheets from the XPages runtime itself. In my experience, you will usually need to make some modifications to the stylesheets your using, but it's doable.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the Wordpress CSS will refer to CSS classes that you have to use in your XPages app. Alternatively you need to change the CSS to match the classes in use in your app.